# Mask and Clip GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, mask, glsurfaceview

I work with an SDK that provides a rectangular glsurfaceview through a callback.

I want to be able to render this view in a circular layout. (i.e.) I would like to display the view on a circular view

I have tried using masking layout such as using a maskable layout https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout (works great for images, not so much for videos)

How do I go about clipping and rendering this as a circle?

(The background is constantly changing, so i cant overlay a transparent view on top of this video view. The aim is to have a rectangular glsurface view on top of which there is a circular glsurface view)

**UI Objective : **
[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want the layout to look like, or how your app is structured. You can create a mask layer by using a second SurfaceView; you just need to set a closer Z-depth for the mask layer. If you have access to the video source, you can direct it to a SurfaceTexture, and then use a custom shader to modify the rendering (e.g. for each fragment, compute the distance from the center, and render as transparent black if it's outside the circle). See Grafika for various examples (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: @fadden Edited the post to add an image of what the UI will look like. Wont having that may surfaceviews be an issue? I don't have access to the video source - it is a continuous live-video-stream. Thanks for the leads , I'll checkout grafika.

Comment: @lavi did you get solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same requirement with a project right now, which involves masking a GLSurfaceView provided by [PexKit](https://github.com/pexip/pexkit-sdk). The solution that works for me is making a subclass of FrameLayout (or any other ViewGroup) and placing the GLSurfaceView inside it.

Then in the FrameLayout subclass use canvas.clipPath:

```
private Path clippingPath;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
        int radius = Math.min(w, h)/2;
        clippingPath = new Path();
        clippingPath.addCircle(w/2, h/2, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    }
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int count = canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(clippingPath);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(count);
}
```