# how to mask a portion of GLSurfaceView in android

Tags: android, mask, glsurfaceview

I have a custom GLSurfaceView that I want to mask a portion of.
Lets say I only want to draw a circular portion of it on screen.

I tried to override the dispathDraw method and use the clipPath method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830469/mask-and-clip-glsurfaceview)

I ensured that the Hardware Acceleration is turned off but the GLsurfaceView renders without any change.

**EDIT 1**

[image]

I realized now that in android studio, after i hit run, the preview does update to show a clipped GLSurfaceView. The output on the screen remains rectangular.

**EDIT 2**
I figured that this only happens when the child view of the parent FrameLayout is GlSurfaceView. WHen I replace that with a imageview (containing blue background) it works as expected on the device.
[image]
Any suggestions?